# Define inverse Laplace operator as map from functions to functions

Tags: differential-equations, functional-style

I am trying to implement the inverse Laplace operator through

```
P[g_] := h /.NDSolve[{h''[x] == g[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

If I now define some $f$ and apply $P$,

```
f[x_] = 0.5 - Abs[x - 0.5]; 
P[f]
```

I do get an InterpolatingFunction, that takes the correct values, i.e.  P[f][0.5] is defined and is what I expect. 
However, if I try to add a normalization of the solution,

```
P[g_] := h/h[0.5] /.NDSolve[{h''[x] == g[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

then I get `-24.*InterpolatingFunction{...}`, which cannot be evaluated, i.e. P[f][0.5] gives `(-24.*InterpolatingFunction{...})[0.5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this,

```
P[g_] := h[#]/h[0.5] & /. 
  NDSolve[{h''[x] == g[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

or like this

```
P[g_] := With[{h = 
    NDSolveValue[{h''[x] == g[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, 
     h, {x, 0, 1}]}, h[#]/h[.5] &]
```

Both evaluate as expected,

```
P[f][.5]
(* 1. *)
```

Comment: Works, but when I try to evaluate a derivative with $ND[P[f][s],s,0.7]$ I get a non-numerical output containing ND itself and a few interpolatingFunctions

Comment: I can't reproduce that, for me `ND[P[f][s], s, 0.7]` gives an error but then gives the right answer.  You can get the same answer without the `NumericalCalculus` package by evaluating `D[P[f][s], s] /. s -> .3`.  Maybe you need to clear the definition of `s`?

Comment: clearing `s` worked